# Is a comma needed to offset an expansion clause?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

**Which of the following is most grammatically correct?**

1. In Boston, and other cities above a certain size, public transit is paid for with an RFID card.
2. In Boston and other cities above a certain size, public transit is paid for with an RFID card.
3. In Boston, and in other cities above a certain size, public transit is paid for with an RFID card.
4. In Boston and in other cities above a certain size, public transit is paid for with an RFID card.

The odd-numbered ones have a first comma the others don't, and the higher-numbered ones have an extra "in" that the first two don't.

I think the first comma is needed to offset the phrase, indicating that the sentence can be read without that part of it.

I'm not sure if the "in" is really necessary and am partial to removing unnecessary words for more concise writing, but would like to leave in anything grammatically needed.

I don't think the phrase "and other cities above a certain size" is an [appositive](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/example-of-an-appositive-noun.html), because it's not another word or phrase for Boston that would be a nonrestrictive descriptor (e.g. "In Boston, the capital of Massachusetts, ..."), nor does it qualify as a [clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause).   The phrase expands the set which becomes the setting of the sentence and thus broadens its meaning or application.

Comment: No, and 2. The comma is not needed, and no need to duplicate "in."

Comment: The commas indicate that the other cities are an aside, extraneous information to the main discussion about Boston. Leave out the commas, and your main point concerns several cities, not just Boston.

Comment: @deadrat You don't think that sentence needs any commas at all?  (The fact that the main clause of the sentence applies to other cities *is* an aside; someone could skip over that without missing the main point of the sentence but could also get additional information from reading that aside.)

Comment: @WBT If the discussion is about cities (with Boston the first mentioned), then to my taste, the introductory prepositional phrase is long enough to merit a following comma. If the discussion is about Boston, with an aside about other cities, then a comma should follow *Boston*. I can't tell which the author intends.

Comment: @deadrat The latter: the discussion is primarily about Boston, with an aside about other cities.

Comment: Then that should tell you where to put the commas, no?

Comment: #1 is the original, but a professional editor corrected it to #2.  Is there any citeable grammatical rule to clearly express *why* the best one is best?

Comment: This is not a matter of grammar. They're all grammatical. None of them is incorrectly punctuated. What deadrat is saying is that you (or your editor) can choose whether or not to highlight Boston; using parenthetical setting-off around {and ... size} (ie two commas) and/or adding the second 'in' gives special prominence to Boston. Version 2 gives a lot less prominence.

Comment: I would only object (mildly) to #4.  And it should be noted that in 2 and 4 the final comma is not required.

Comment: To answer your question "You don't think that sentence needs any commas at all?" I think the answer is that someone who likes to be frugal with their commas could write the sentence without any, and it would still be grammatically correct.  And reasonably understandable.  (I personally wouldn't write it with no commas but I know some people who would.)